How do I build a specific Python structure of a 2D array of 1D arrays?
How do I build a specific structure of a 2D array of 1D arrays (i. row vectors) to meet the specific
structure of a legacy programme I am maintaining?
I can generate the right content, in this structure
all_measurements[:12]
array([[0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 2.   ],
       [0.02 , 0.334, 0.04 , 2.24 ],
       [0.04 , 0.668, 0.08 , 2.48 ],   .....

but the programme needs it in this structure
array([array([[0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 2.   ]]),
       array([[0.02 , 0.334, 0.04 , 2.24 ]]),
       array([[0.04 , 0.668, 0.08 , 2.48 ]]),

Here is the code I am currently using
import numpy as np

dt = 1/50; nt = 350
Vh = 16.7; Vv = 20.6; Vy = 2
gg = -10; v0 = +2

it = np.arange(nt)
ts = dt * it

all_measurements = []

for i in range(12):
    row = np.array([ts[i], Vh*ts[i], Vy*ts[i], (v0 + ts[i]*(Vy - gg))])
    all_measurements.append(row)

all_measurements = np.array(all_measurements)

The code above generates the test case data, but the parser rejects the data in this format with the error message

too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed
measurements[row_list[np.where(column_list == i)[0]],:])

As per my comment below, it has resolved by tweaking the loop to
for i in range(nt):
    row = np.array([np.array([ts[i], Vh*ts[i], Vy*ts[i], (v0 + ts[i]*(Vy - gg *ts[i]))])])
    all_measurements.append(row)

Follow on question, I know the row count is small (100's to low 1000's), but is initialising  all_measurements  to an empty list then iteratively appending not very inefficient in terms of memory management, and raw machine cycles?

You don't mean that your lists merely need to be wrapped in another list, do you? E.g., changing all_measurements.append(row) to all_measurements.append([row])?

I think I figured it out, that row = statement simply follows the pattern in the structure the debug console reported
row = np.array([np.array([ts[i], Vh*ts[i], Vy*ts[i], (v0 + ts[i]*(Vy - gg *ts[i]))])])

Why on earth would the original developer wrap it up in such a complicated fashion?

The structure you provided as the needed structure is one dimensional

@russhoppa  I guess it's what you wrote.  It's a double np.array([]))  construct for some weird reason.
The programme accepts the data and runs to completion, now I move on to functional evaluation of it - hopefully the code issues will be small now.

If you have the answer that you need, please close the question.

@VoNWooDSoN  I would if I could, there is no answer to accept, I cannot answer it either to be able to accept and close on that answer.
And I don't want to delete it - so what next?

If you solved the question yourself without help from an answer, post an answer yourself describing the solution, and then accept that.
